# Caching Django Responses with mod_wsgi and Apache2 mem_cache

Tags: python, django, caching, apache2, httpresponse

I've followed the following article in an attempt to setup Apache2 caching in order to use it with Django on Ubuntu 12.10 with mod_wsgi. I want Apache to cache some requests for me.

```
http://www.howtoforge.com/caching-with-apaches-mod_cache-on-ubuntu-10.04
```

From the article I enabled the modules and setup the following php script to test the caching. The caching works just fine - I only get a new timestamp after 5 minutes.

```
vi /var/www/cachetest.php

<?php
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=300");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
echo time()."<br>";
?>
```

Now in my django response, I return an HttpResponse object after setting the appropriate headers the same way:

```
# Create a Response Object with the content to return and set it's 
response = HttpResponse("%s"%(output_display))
response['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate, max-age=20'
response['Vary'] = 'Accept-Encoding'
return response
```

The caching with the Django request doesn't work at all. I've used Firefox's LiveHeaders to examine the HTTP response headers.

For the example link above and the PHP script the headers look like:

```
http://localhost/cachetest.php

GET /cachetest.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Mar 2013 02:29:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=300
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 34
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------------------------------------
```

For my Django Request - the caching doesn't work, it always forces the lengthy operation to complete the response - just like re-loading the php request above with F5. Using the FireFox plugin I seem to be writing the correct headers:

```
http://localhost/testdjango/testdjango/

GET /testdjango/testdjango/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Mar 2013 02:32:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=20
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
----------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the django caching to work like the php script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be your problem:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

It means a 'streaming response', in terms of mod_mem_cache. And, according to the docs:

> By default, a streamed response will not be cached unless it has a
>   Content-Length header.

You can solve it by setting the [MCacheMaxStreamingBuffer directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mem_cache.html#mcachemaxstreamingbuffer).

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've tried to set the appropriate headers in Django, but they are somehow being overridden. Please see my subsequent question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323619/django-response-always-chunked-with-text-html-cannot-set-content-length. Would you have any other ideas for this? Thanks -

Comment: Didn't `MCacheMaxStreamingBuffer` fix your problem? According to the Apache documentation it should, even when the transfer encoding is `chunked` *and* your response doesn't have a Content-Length set (which is probably stripped by `mod_wsgi`, although that's just a guess).

Comment: No it didn't - you can see my config file in the secondary post. Something else is going on.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any further, I don't use mod_wsgi myself so I don't have it running to test if I reproduce your problem. I hope someone can answer your second post :)