# Django Response always Chunked with text/html cannot set Content-Length

Tags: python, django, http, http-headers, apache2

In my Django Application's views.py , I return an HttpResponse object after attempting to set the following HTTP Header fields:

```
# Create a Response Object with the content to return 
response = HttpResponse("%s"%(output_display),mimetype='text/html')
response['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate, max-age=20'
response['Vary'] = 'Accept-Encoding'
response['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
#response['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
response['Connection'] = 'close'
#response['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
response['Content-Length'] = '%s'%(len(output_display))
return response
```

I then capture the output using the Live HTTP Headers plugin with FireFox, and it looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Mar 2013 14:55:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked   <---------- Why 'chunked'?
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=20
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html <---------------------- No Content-Length even though I set it?
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

I am trying to cache using Apache2's mem_cache, so I need the Content-Length to be set and cannot have 'chunked' for Transfer-Encoding.

My Apache2 mem_cache.conf looks like ( large numbers just for testing ):

```
<IfModule mod_mem_cache.c>
        CacheEnable mem /
        MCacheSize 10000
        MCacheMaxObjectCount 10000000
        MCacheMinObjectSize 1
        MCacheMaxObjectSize 10000000
        MCacheMaxStreamingBuffer 10000000
</IfModule>
```

But even though I explicitly set the Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding in my response code, 'chunked' is inserted automatically and therefore my Content-Length is not honored. Why is this? How can I fix this to get the desired response? Thanks -

Comment: Content-Length cannot be present together with Transfer-Encoding https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar issue recently with a mod_wsgi application; I was trying to update an apache configuration that was using its built-in disk cache, to use socache/memcache instead.

The disk cache was working, but switching to memcache or shmcb didn't work. If I issued a request for a resource I wanted cached, it wouldn't store it in the cache (`CacheDetailHeader` is helpful for this). Checking the logs at debug, I found the message:

```
[Wed Dec 05 18:52:16.571002 2018] [cache_socache:debug] \
[pid 884:tid 140422596777728] mod_cache_socache.c(389): \
[client 127.0.0.1:56576] AH02346: URL 'http://127.0.1.1:80/cacheme/c?' \
had no explicit size, ignoring, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
```

It seems that socache doesn't like objects that don't have explicit sizes. I tried setting the newer, socache equivalents of those mod_memcache settings to sufficiently large values: `CacheSocacheMaxSize` and `CacheSocacheReadSize`.

I know that the `Content-Length` header was being set and made it through to somewhere; it showed up in the mod_wsgi logs when I deliberately miscalculated it.

A few things I found:

1. Don't set `Transfer-Encoding` header yourself, as this is forbidden by the WSGI specification:

   > [Who set the Transfer-Encoding: chunked header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621559/who-set-the-transfer-encoding-chunked-header)
2. Even though you're setting the `Content-Length` header yourself, it's also being gzipped by apache. This changes the length; when Apache doesn't know what the length will be, it switches to chunked and removes the `Content-Length` header.

I found that with:

- `Content-Type: text/html`
- `Content-Length` set to my utf-8 encoding size

set in the python/mod_wsgi application, and:

- `SetEnv no-gzip 1`

set in the apache configuration, that the object made it into a shmcb cache.

It looks like when apache gzips an object, it changes the headers to that it isn't accepted by socache.

I looked around for ways to make them compatible, but couldn't find too much on this issue. There is some mention of reordering the cache/deflate filters in the mod_cache documentation:

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#finecontrol

This worked if I put in a directive to reorder the cache/deflate filters:

```
# within a directory
SetOutputFilter CACHE;DEFLATE
```

Curiously, on a cache miss, the server returned gzipped content, but on a cache hit, the server returned unencoded text/html. This looks odd, but I haven't understood the FilterChain directives well enough to try those out.

I also found some mention of this in a related issue with php/content-length:

> https://serverfault.com/questions/183843/content-length-not-sent-when-gzip-compression-enabled-in-apache

The answer there found that if they set the `DeflateBufferSize` to a large-enough value, then content-length would be set.

I couldn't get this to work.

So it looks like one is stuck between choosing cached or gzipped.