# Who set the Transfer-Encoding: chunked header?

Tags: django, apache, http, mod-wsgi

I am using Django, mod_wsgi and Apache.
When I make a response as StreamingHttpResponse and return, Transfer-Encoding: chunked header is set in the response.
But when I add the Content-Length header to the resposne, Transfer-Encoding header is removed and only the Content-Length header exists.

Who set and remove the Transfer-Encoding header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache will set `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` when you don't specify a content length. You should not attempt to set that header yourself. The WSGI specification actually forbids you (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#id34) from setting, as it is a hop-by-hop header.

When a content length is set, HTTP doesn't need to use chunked response encoding.

Comment: You say that If the Content-Length header does not exists, Apache sets the Transfer-Encoding: chunked header. If I set the Content-Length header, Apache will not set the Transfer-Encoding. I must not set the Transfer-Encoding header in my application. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, never set ``Transfer-Encoding`` yourself, it is not your job. That is up to the underlying web server used as you cannot control the actual chunking in the response.